# Is "that would be correct" always followed by an if statement?

Tags: sentence-meaning, conditional-constructions, sentence-usage

I have always thought when people use the phrase "That would be correct", it is always followed by some "if" statement; for example,

> Jane: "Is it correct to say that people are allowed to turn right when the traffic light is red?"
>   Tom: "That would be correct *if they live in Canada or US*."

But how should I interpret the sentence "That would be correct" when there is no "if" statement that follows? For example, I was having some conversation with my teacher:

> me: "Is this statement correct?"
>   Teacher: "Yes. That statement would be correct."

How should I interpret the teacher's sentence?

Answer (score 3):

Using *would* in:

> That statement **would be** correct.

makes it indirect and somewhat noncommittal. There could be an implied (though not spoken) if or however clause after it. Also somewhat informal (after all, you are the student).
The usage *would be* more likely when the statement is not factual and is open to interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, we use "that would be" to comment on a suggestion or a possibility.
for example:
- You might want to go there and see some of the professors. -- That would be great. 
or
 - I might go to Bracken next year.     -- That would be awesome.