# No, $50 is enough, I would have thought

Tags: modal-verbs

John: "I gave the waiter a $50 dollar tip and he gave me a dirty look. Maybe I should have given him more?"

Bill: "No, $50 **is** enough, I would have thought."

Should it be: "No, $50 **was/would be** enough, I would have thought"?

Comment: All three would work but I would avoid the repetition of would.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["That would be correct"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/90671/that-would-be-correct) Also [Would be or will be](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/253090/use-of-would-be-vs-is) and [Use of “Would be” vs. “Is”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/253090/use-of-would-be-vs-is) and [Use of “would be” vs. “is”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/106901/use-of-would-be-vs-is), among others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you regard *I/you would have thought* as an idiom, meaning "that is my/your judgment or opinion". It can be used with any tense:

> John knew it, I would have thought.

> John knows it, I would have thought.

> John will be there, I would have thought.

though it doesn't work well with a statement whose truth can be objectively determined:

> ? John was there, I would have thought.